# How to configure sampling for java application dependency calls using the dependency properties in applicationinsights.json file

Tags: java, azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

I have deployed a java application in AKS with Appinsights. I am using `applicationinsights.json` to configure the appinsights in the service deployed.
And I want to sample the dependency calls which has `Base name` property with certain value as per the below screenshot.

[image]

I have used below `applicationinsights.json` configuration file. But it did not work for me.
I tried with strict and Regex both but that also did not work.
Can someone please tell me how I can sample the above dependency call with `Base name` property or any other properties if possible.

```
{
    "role": {
        "name": "ROLE_NAME"
    },
    "heartbeat": {
        "intervalSeconds": 60
    },
    "preview": {
        "processors": [
            {
                "type": "attribute",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "key": "http.url",
                        "pattern": "(?<redacted>\\?.*)",
                        "replace": "\\?***",
                        "action": "mask"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "/log/maskQueryString"
            }
        ],
        "sampling": {
            "overrides": [
                {
                    "telemetryType": "dependency",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "key": "Base name",
                            "value": "<value of the property>",
                            "matchType": "strict"
                        }
                    ],
                    "percentage": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sample my DB dependency calls by adding the below sampling configs in my applicationinsights.json config file

```
{
    "preview": {
        "sampling": {
            "overrides": [
                {
                    "telemetryType": "dependency",
                    "attributes": [
                        {
                            "key": "db.system",
                            "value": ".*sql.*",
                            "matchType": "regexp"
                        }
                    ],
                    "percentage": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```